# proguard-android-optimize build failed

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

i am trying to disable all logs

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {

public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** d(...);
public static *** e(...);
```

}

```
 -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

but when i set

```
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

build faild
error

```
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
... 4 more
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

with this 
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
 its  build but logs are visible

The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.

Comment: there might be some other error as well. Please check again.

Comment: check edit qus  Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(android.support.v7.widget.by) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute.  this type of error coming wtih different package name like (android.support.v7.widget.bx) ,

Comment: this shows that you have to keep the native references. Please post your proguard file

Comment: -keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,LineNumberTable,SourceFile
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

###remove log####
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {

    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'],exclude: 'android-support-*.jar')

Comment: You have wrong proguard file. I post the correct file inwhich native methods need to keep as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102436/discussion-between-andro-and-mustansar-saeed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following `proguard` for the reference as during optimizations, native methods need to keep as it is.

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 native <methods>;
}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very popular but incorrect ProGuard config. AAPT automaticalle creates rules to keep classes mentioned in manifest, so Activities won't be stripped. But this config, for example, keeps even abstract activities.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a dummy `Log` class in package `com.example.mylog` with *NOPs* for `v,i,w,d,e` and then use this proguard remapping

```
android.util.Log -> com.example.mylog.Log
```

wiht the option `-applymapping`